# authenticate() is not running with custom authentication backend

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication

I' m trying to add a new authentication backend to my project with the following versions and code snippets:

django: 2.2.1
python: 3.5.2
mysql-server: 5.7

#### settings.py

```
...
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['common.backends.MyOwnAuthenticationBackend']
```

#### common/backends.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class MyOwnAuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
    print('MOAB')
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        print('AUTH')
        ...

    def get_user(self, username):
        print('GETUSER')
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

While trying to log in, i get back the **MOAB**, but none of the **AUTH** or **GETUSER** strings.

What can be the reason for it?

The main urls.py contains the following for authentication:

## urls.py

```
from common import views as common_views
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.urls import path

...

url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.LoginView, name='auth_login'),

...
```

What did i miss? I read many questions and posts about it on the Internet, but i can' t figure out why the **authenticate()** method is not called at all.

Comment: Good guess. Thanks. It seems i was looking some older documentation, not for my current django version.

Comment: I don' t know what did i do. Maybe i deleted the answer from someone? Someone wrote to use request in the authenticate, like (def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None): which solved my problem. Sorry if it was me who deleted... .

Comment: :) no it's my bad, i said that before checking in different versions so i deleted the comment. glad it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method should look like :

```
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
```

You can can check the parameters needed for the signature of the method `authenticate` by looking at the [source of authentication system](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L61). The first positioned parameter is `request`, and then the credentials are unpacked as named parameters:

```
def authenticate(request=None, **credentials):
    """
    If the given credentials are valid, return a User object.
    """
    for backend, backend_path in _get_backends(return_tuples=True):
        try:
            inspect.getcallargs(backend.authenticate, request, **credentials)
        except TypeError:
            # This backend doesn't accept these credentials as arguments. Try the next one.
            continue
        try:
            user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
     [...]
```

(`_get_backends` represents the list of all backends in settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS)

Doc about custom authentication :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend